# Reading digits from text file C++

Tags: c++, cin

I have a code in a file and it looks like

> 73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934 96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843 85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511

and etc. 20 lines in total. What I want to do is to read every two digit from the text file and put them into an array of integers(one element = two digits). How can I read only two digits by time from this text file, not the whole line?

Comment: Where's your current code? You can ready byte by byte. If you know the file is in ASCII, then each "number" is a single byte, so read 2 bytes at a time.

Comment: can you explain it more

Comment: No, you only provided us a sample of the file you are trying to parse...

Comment: Why not just read the whole line and then do whatever you want with it after you've read it?

Comment: @crush i mean can you put your way as a code ??

Comment: @AboJihadBazoka No. You put the C++ code you've tried to write so far in the question. THEN we will help you. We're not going to do your homework assignment for you. Show us what you've tried so far, or you get no help.

Comment: @crush [Here](http://pastebin.com/8p6PXkEE) is my whole program,it  should read a text and encrypt it, then decrypt it

Comment: I did 60% from the job and i could make the program encrypt the text and the way back it's just to reverse the steps back but i don't know how can i read two digits by time

Comment: Do you want the 2 digits to be a string of two digits, or do you want it to be converted from ASCII to an integer (a number, not string)?

Comment: So you are able to encrypt and decrypt text, but can't read two digits at a time from a file?

Comment: @ruben2020 He wants it converted into an `int`. So, parsing `'73'` becomes `int number = 73;`

Answer (score 4):

Well, you could read the whole line first, then split it into two digits at a time. Or you could simply use

```
char twodigits[2];
twodigits[0] = fin.get();
twodigits[1] = fin.get();
```

Comment: He'll need to do some bitshifting to make the integers right.

Comment: +1 pretty much what I was going to suggest. Looks like a homework problem, so getting any more specific does him no favors.

Comment: Bitshifting is difficult if you need to multiply by ten, but I guess you can do that... Assuming it's base 10.

Comment: And yes, I'm not going to write the code for someone's homework - unless I can obfuscate it enough that the teacher will twig immediately that it's not written by the student... ;)

Comment: True, I didn't notice it wasn't hexadecimal. He could multiply by 10 after the first assignment, then add the second.

Comment: That is, after he subtracted the ASCII offset.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Mats Petersson's answer:

```
char twodigits[2];
int integerr;
twodigits[0] = fin.get() - '0'; // convert from ASCII
twodigits[1] = fin.get() - '0'; // convert from ASCII
integerr = twodigits[0] * 10 + twodigits[1];
```

And also, you need to skip the end-of-line character(s). This also depends on which platform you are on - Windows, Linux, Mac, as all three have different EOLs.

EOL characters are of 0x0A and 0x0D combinations, while numbers are 0x30 and above, so you can use this for detection. I leave it to you to explore.

Comment: It would be clearer to use '0' instead of 0x30.

Comment: Agreed! You are right.